Update leader election failed. error="context deadline exceeded": Deployment Using the ArangoDB Starter in Docker
I have created 3 AWS EC2 t2.micro instances. Followed the steps from here: Deployment Using the ArangoDB Starter inDocker. Using security group, I'm allowing Inbound rules Custom TCP for 8528, 8529, 8530 and 8531 ports.
"Added new peer" log appears properly after joining from other instances but after some time it fails with following error "Update leader election failed. error="context deadline exceeded""

There are the cmds I'm executing on each instance:
On instanse A:
export IP=172.31.##.#5
docker volume create arangodb1
docker run -it --name=adb1 --rm -p 8528:8528 \
    -v arangodb1:/data \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    arangodb/arangodb-starter \
    --starter.address=$IP

On Instance B:
export IP=172.31.##.#4
docker volume create arangodb2
docker run -it --name=adb2 --rm -p 8528:8528 \
    -v arangodb2:/data \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    arangodb/arangodb-starter \
    --starter.address=$IP \
    --starter.join 172.31.##.#5

On Instance C:
export IP=172.31.##.##2
docker volume create arangodb3
docker run -it --name=adb3 --rm -p 8528:8528 \
    -v arangodb3:/data \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    arangodb/arangodb-starter \
    --starter.address=$IP \
    --starter.join 172.31.##.#5

Note: # in IP address pertains to a number.
